# User-forget-password implementation in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web

I'm trying to use ASP.NET MVC to implement the functionality of user retrieving his password once he forget it. This functionality uses SMS authenticating mechanism for verifying users who forget their password and the procedure of that functionality is listed as follows:

1. User types his username on a text input of the web page and click "submit" button.
2. The system checks the user in database with the input user name.

   2.1 If the user is not found in database, the system will display a message that the given user name is not correct.

   2.2 Otherwise the system will retrieve the phone number field of that user.
3. The system generates a 6-digits verifying code and send it to the mobile phone of that user by invoking external SMS Web Service.
4. The system displays a form and ask user to input the verifying code he gets from his mobile phone and click "submit" button.
5. The system compares the input code with the stored code.

   5.1 If the two codes is the same, the system will display the password of that user.

   5.2 Otherwise, the system will display a message that the given code is incorrect.

When implementing it, step 1 to 3 is relatively OK to me, but from step 4 on, I don't know what's a good way to make it. To be specific, I can come up with three questions so far:

1. How could the system handle step 4?  Should the controller redirect to a different page for retrieving the input of verifying code? Or everything just need to be put 
   on one single page and the controller just reload it?
2. Where should I store the verifying code and password after step 3? Would the Controller or Model be destructed with the variables it stored lost from that moment on? If so, they have to pass the stored code and password to somewhere else. Should it be Session, TempData, ViewData or otherwhere?
3. Which layer of the system should handle the code validation logic at Step 5? The Model, View or Controller?

Comment: "*the system will display the password of that user*" - This should not be possible as you should not be storing passwords, you should be storing the hashes of passwords.  You would generate a new temporary password for the user and display that.  Don't forget to add a TTL value for the PIN codes alongside throttle control.  Consider longer codes.

Comment: By _the system will display the password of that user_, I hope you mean display a temporary password and not their actual password. After step 1, you can just redirect to another page to display the input for the code

Comment: @AlexK. storing password is just an example to make the scenario in this question simpler. I won't do it in real world.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I think that page can't be redirected to and displayed until the system have found the user with the given username, otherwise the system need to return a wrong message to the original page.

Comment: Yes but if the username is not found when you submit it, then you would return the view to display the validation error, but if its is run the code to generate the 'verifying code', send it, persist the data somewhere (ideally to a database), and redirect to the view to enter the code